# immutablsjs order of Map.entrySeq

Tags: immutable.js

I have following piece of code

`[array with keys].reduce((acc, key) => acc.set(key, 1), Map());`

Map is immutablejs Map not js Map. When I call Map.entrySeq() on it it always gives me the same order in which I executed set() in reduce.

Can I realy on this order?

Comment: I guess OrderedMap is the way...

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) of immutable.js is good, you can rely on it. To quote:

```
Iteration order of a Map is undefined, however is stable. 
Multiple iterations of the same Map will iterate in the same order.
```

So the answer is yes. Note that your piece of code has terrible performance, it creates a new map N times.

Use `withMutations` to execute all manipulations on temporary, mutable map:

```
Immutable.Map().withMutations(mutableMap => {
  [array with keys].reduce((acc, key) => acc.set(key, 1), mutableMap);
});
```